# FlexStridedSlice operator not supported on embedded tflite_runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflite

I am trying to convert a frozen graph to a tflite model, which I need to deploy on an embedded runtime.

The version of the tflite_runtime is 2.11.1

The following code was used to convert .pb graph to tflite on a different machine than the final runtime.

```
import tensorflow as tf

#Directory of the saved model (frozen graph)
saved_model_dir="my.pb"

# Load the graph as before

graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
with tf.io.gfile.GFile(saved_model_dir, 'rb') as f:
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())


tf.compat.v1.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

# Access the default graph
graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()

#collect all tensor names
tensor_names = []
for op in graph.get_operations():
    for tensor in op.values():
        tensor_names.append(tensor.name)
#retrieve the inpue and oupt tensors
input_tensors = [tensor_names[0][0:-2]]
output_tensors = [tensor_names[-2][0:-2],tensor_names[-1][0:-2]]

##

#coonvert to tflite model
converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
    graph_def_file=saved_model_dir,
    input_arrays=input_tensors,  
    output_arrays=output_tensors,  
    input_shapes={'input': [1, 108, 192, 2]}  # Adjust based on your input shape
)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, 
                                       tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
quantized_tflite_model = converter.convert()

#save the model
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(quantized_tflite_model)
```

Attempted to invoke the converted .tflite model on the embedded runtime which gives an error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 513, in allocate_tensors
    return self._interpreter.AllocateTensors()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Select TensorFlow op(s), included in the given model, is(are) not supported by this interpreter. Make sure you apply/link the Flex delegate before inference. For the Android, it can be resolved by adding "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops" dependency. See instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_selectNode number 228 (FlexStridedSlice) failed to prepare.Select TensorFlow op(s), included in the given model, is(are) not supported by this interpreter. Make sure you apply/link the Flex delegate before inference. For the Android, it can be resolved by adding "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops" dependency. See instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_selectNode number 228 (FlexStridedSlice) failed to prepare.
```

When I check all the operators used in the model I have the following list:

```
'DEQUANTIZE', 'MUL', 'SUB', 'STRIDED_SLICE', 'PAD', 'CONCATENATION', 'CONV_2D', 'LEAKY_RELU', 'TRANSPOSE_CONV', 'SPLIT', 'TILE', 'RESHAPE', 'GATHER', 'ABS', 'SUM', 'ARG_MIN', 'CAST', 'ZEROS_LIKE', 'CONV_3D_TRANSPOSE', 'ADD', 'FLOOR', 'MINIMUM', 'MAXIMUM', 'BROADCAST_TO', 'FlexStridedSlice', 'PACK', 'FlexTranspose', 'SLICE'
```

1. How can I check on the runtime to discover supported operators?
2. How do I change the frozen graph to use compatible operators?